# Where are the NPC traders in Pokemon Sword/Shield and what do they offer?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

In each Pokemon game I usually make a point of trading with each NPC that offers one.

Where are the traders in Sword/Shield? Which Pokemon do they offer and what do they want in return?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are plenty of trades to perform in Sword/Shield! Here's the ones I've been able to find, as well as some from other sources

### Both Games:

These trades are available in both games:

1. **Bunnelby → Skwovet ♂** (*Motostoke Pokemon Center*)
   <sub>**Nickname:** Cheekers, **Level:** 10, **Nature:** *Mild*, **Ability:** *Cheek Pouch*, **Held Item:** *Oran Berry*, **Dynamax:** *1*</sub>

   - Tackle
   - Tail Whip
   - Bite
   - Stuff Cheeks
2. **Meowth (Galar) → Meowth (Kanto) ♂** (*Turrfield Gym*)
   <sub>**Nickname:** Cash, **Level:** 18, **Nature:** *Timid*, **Ability:** *Technician*, **Held Item:** *Sitrus Berry*, **Dynamax:** *1*</sub>

   - Scratch
   - Pay Day
   - Bite
   - Last Resort
3. **Minccino → Cottonee ♀** (*Hulbury Market*)
   <sub>**Nickname:** Candyfloss, **Level:** 23, **Nature:** *Modest*, **Ability:** *Prankster*, **Held Item:** *None*, **Dynamax:** *1*</sub>

   - Mega Drain
   - Razor Leaf
   - Growth
   - Last Resort
4. **Toxel → Togepi ♀** (*Hammerlocke - Outside Vault*)
   <sub>**Nickname:** Snips, **Level:** 25, **Nature:** *Timid*, **Ability:** *Serene Grace*, **Held Item:** *None*, **Dynamax:** *1*</sub>

   - Ancient Power
   - Yawn
   - Metronome
   - Life Dew
5. **Yamask (Galar) → Yamask (Unova) ♂** (*Ballonlea Gym*)
   <sub>**Nickname:** Masky, **Level:** 36, **Nature:** *Bold*, **Ability:** *Mummy*, **Held Item:** *None*, **Dynamax:** *2*</sub>

   - Hex
   - Mean Look
   - Grudge
   - Will-O-Wisp
6. **Obstagoon → Mr. Mime (Kanto) ♂** (*Spikemuth - Near battle area*)
   <sub>**Nickname:** Mymo, **Level:** 40, **Nature:** *Calm*, **Ability:** *Soundproof*, **Held Item:** *None*, **Dynamax:** *1*</sub>

   - Light Screen
   - Reflect
   - Safeguard
   - Sucker Punch
7. **Frosmoth → Duraludon ♂** (*Wyndon - 4th house down from the stadium*)
   <sub>**Nickname:** Linear, **Level:** 50, **Nature:** *Adamant*, **Ability:** *Heavy Metal*, **Held Item:** *None*, **Dynamax:** *3*</sub>

   - Iron Defense
   - Laser Focus
   - Dragon Claw
   - Night Slash

---

### Version-Exclusive Trades:

These trades are exclusive to either Sword or Shield as noted below:

1. (Sword) **Maractus → Hatenna ♀** (*Stow-on-Side - Top of leftmost building*)
   <sub>**Nickname:** Fringe, **Level:** 30, **Nature:** *Quiet*, **Ability:** *Anticipation*, **Held Item:** *None*, **Dynamax:** *1*</sub>

   - Aromatherapy
   - Psybeam
   - Heal Pulse
   - Dazzling Gleam
2. (Shield) **Maractus → Impidimp ♂** (*Stow-on-Side - Top of leftmost building*)
   <sub>**Nickname:** Peepers, **Level:** 30, **Nature:** *Random*, **Ability:** *Anticipation*, **Held Item:** *None*, **Dynamax:** *1*</sub>

   - Assurance
   - Swagger
   - Sucker Punch
   - Torment
3. (Sword) **Vanillish  → Throh ♂** (*Circhester  - Ice cream stall*)
   <sub>**Nickname:** Reddos, **Level:** 37, **Nature:** *Adamant*, **Ability:** *Inner Focus*, **Held Item:** *None*, **Dynamax:** *2*</sub>

   - Revenge
   - Bulk Up
   - Storm Throw
   - Vital Throw
4. (Shield) **Vanillish  → Sawk ♂** (*Circhester  - Ice cream stall*)
   <sub>**Nickname:** Bluebop, **Level:** 37, **Nature:** *Adamant*, **Ability:** *Inner Focus*, **Held Item:** *None*, **Dynamax:** *2*</sub>

   - Low Sweep
   - Bulk Up
   - Retaliate
   - Brick Break

---

Sources for the ones I was unable to find originally:

- [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/swordshield/ingametrade.shtml) (Version exclusive differences for Shield)
- [IGN](https://au.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-sword-shield/Every_NPC_Trade_Quest_in_Pokemon_Sword_and_Shield)